# How to plot 3D discontinuous iterative plot?

Tags: plotting, functions, graphics3d, piecewise, discontinuity

I am having troubles with plotting this set of data

> triples={{0, 1, 1}, {9/50, 4/5, 1}}, {{9/50, 4/5, 1}, {3/8, 4/5, 1}},     {{3/8, 58333/100000, 1}, {3/4, 16667/100000, 1}}, {{3/4, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 2}, {27/100, 4/5, 2}}, {{27/100, 4/5, 2}, {9/16, 4/5, 2}}, {{9/16, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 2}},
>    {{0, 1, 3}, {81/200, 4/5, 3}}, {{81/200, 4/5, 3}, {21/32, 4/5, 3}}, {{21/32, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 3}},
>    {{0, 1, 4}, {243/400, 4/5, 4}}, {{243/400, 0, 4}, {1, 0, 4}},{{0, 1, 5}, {471/800, 43539/50000, 5}}, {{471/800, 0, 5}, {1, 0, 5}}

At first I had pairs of points, after I added the third coordinate to be able to plot it in 3D, but the problem now is I cant plot it, because every iteration is given by piecewise linear part, by intervals. 
I would like to get 3D plot from this set of points, where every coordinate z is one iteration.

For plotting I use this

> Show[ListPointPlot3D[triples, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
>     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 5}}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
>     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}], Graphics3D[Line[triples]]]

but it gives me error: >The specified setting for the option Graphics3DBoxOptions, PlotRange cannot be used.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `triples` needs `{ ... ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
triples = {{{0, 1, 1}, {9/50, 4/5, 1}}, {{9/50, 4/5, 1}, {3/8, 4/5, 
     1}}, {{3/8, 58333/100000, 1}, {3/4, 16667/100000, 1}}, {{3/4, 0, 1}, {1, 
     0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 2}, {27/100, 4/5, 2}}, {{27/100, 4/5, 2}, {9/16, 4/5, 
     2}}, {{9/16, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 2}}, {{0, 1, 3}, {81/200, 4/5, 3}}, {{81/200, 
     4/5, 3}, {21/32, 4/5, 3}}, {{21/32, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 3}}, {{0, 1, 
     4}, {243/400, 4/5, 4}}, {{243/400, 0, 4}, {1, 0, 4}}, {{0, 1, 
     5}, {471/800, 43539/50000, 5}}, {{471/800, 0, 5}, {1, 0, 5}}};
```

**Assuming that you want the lines to be discontinuous.**

```
{zmin, zmax} = MinMax@Flatten[triples, 1][[All, 3]]

(* {1, 5} *)

Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[triples,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}),
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 5}},
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large],
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}],
 Graphics3D[{Thick, {ColorData["Rainbow"][
       Rescale[Mean[#[[All, 3]]], {zmin, zmax}]], Line[#]} & /@ triples}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`tiples` is not a `List`. Maybe you made a mistake when copied here. Add brackets around,

```
triples = {{{0, 1, 1}, {9/50, 4/5, 1}}, {{9/50, 4/5, 1}, {3/8, 4/5, 
     1}}, {{3/8, 58333/100000, 1}, {3/4, 16667/100000, 1}}, {{3/4, 0, 
     1}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 2}, {27/100, 4/5, 2}}, {{27/100, 4/5, 
     2}, {9/16, 4/5, 2}}, {{9/16, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 2}}, {{0, 1, 
     3}, {81/200, 4/5, 3}}, {{81/200, 4/5, 3}, {21/32, 4/5, 
     3}}, {{21/32, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 3}}, {{0, 1, 4}, {243/400, 4/5, 
     4}}, {{243/400, 0, 4}, {1, 0, 4}}, {{0, 1, 5}, {471/800, 
     43539/50000, 5}}, {{471/800, 0, 5}, {1, 0, 5}}};
```

then use `Flatten[triples,1]`  to get a `List` of 3D points.

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[triples, 1], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 5}}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}], Graphics3D[Line[Flatten[triples, 1]]]]
```

[image: fig1]